# Custom discord bot prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need help. I don't know why my prefix of discord bot shows as `undefined` and doesn't work. Here's my code:

```js
let PREFIX;

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`) === null) {
        PREFIX = "$"
    }
    else
    {
        PREFIX = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
    }})

client.prefix = PREFIX;
```

I use quick.db

Comment: Is the `.` inside of `let.prefix` intentional?

Comment: its my fault i mean let PREFIX;

next one is

client.prefix = PREFIX;

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to fix it

```js
if (!db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)) {
    PREFIX = "$"
}else{
    PREFIX = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
}
```

Comment: sorry but your solution don't fix my problem